# How to update an array element in a deeply nested mongodb structure using C# (Trying to use positional operator to update the document))

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to access a deeply nested mongodb structure and want to update and read from the structure using c#. I want to update UUT Object inside UUT arrays and also UUT History array.

I am trying to update the value for UUTId: TS220, clockingcycles : 2000.

I know of one option to overwrite complete document but i don't know how can i access UUTId object and insert a value for clockingcycles.

Please answer using c# MongoDB.Driver
Thanks in advance.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://server.net:27017");
IMongoDatabase db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("enduranceTest");
IMongoCollection<ServerTreeVm> collectionEndurance = db.GetCollection<ServerTreeVm>("EnduranceTests");


var filterVM = Builders<ServerTreeVm>.Filter;
            var enduranceTestFound = filterVM.And(
                Builders<ServerTreeVm>.Filter.Where(x => x.Countries.Any(y =>
                    y.Cities.Any(z => z.EnduranceTests.Any(a => a.EnduranceTestName == "Endurance 1")))),
                Builders<ServerTreeVm>.Filter.Where(x => x.Countries.Any(y =>
                    y.Cities.Any(z => z.EnduranceTests.Any(a => a.EnduranceInfo.Any(b=>b.Title== "Taktverteiler_1"))))),
                Builders<ServerTreeVm>.Filter.Where(x => x.Countries.Any(y =>
                    y.Cities.Any(z => z.EnduranceTests.Any(a => a.EnduranceInfo.Any(b => b.Channels.Any(c=>c.Uuts.Any(d=>d.UutId == "TS220"))))))));

            var enduranceTest = collectionEndurance.Find(enduranceTestFound).SingleOrDefault();

            //update with positional operator
            var update = Builders<ServerTreeVm>.Update;

            UUT uutObj = new UUT
            {
              Status = "Running",
              UutId = "TS220",
              ClockingCycles = 2000,
              Offset = 100,
              StartCycles = 0,
              Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
              UUTHistory = null
            };

            var enduranceUpdate = update.Set("Countries.$.Cities.$.EnduranceTest.$.ClockDistributor.$.Channels.$.UUTs.$", uutObj);
            collectionEndurance.UpdateOne(enduranceTestFound, enduranceUpdate);
```

so i get the entire document from mongodb in C# ServerTreeVM Model and then i am trying to update the document with positional operator. But it is not updating the document. I don't know what am i doing here wrong. Any tips or a different way of doing this?

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5d5ff0be962f936368c28b1f"
  },
  "Countries": [
    {
      "CountryName": "Country1",
      "Cities": [
        {
          "CityName": "City1",
          "EnduranceTests": [
            {
              "EnduranceTestName": "endurance1",
              "ClockDistributor": [
                {
                  "IP": "192.168.2.6",
                  "Channels": [
                    {
                      "UUTs": [
                        {
                          "UUTId": "TS220",
                          "ClockingCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Status": "Steht",
                          "StartCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Offset": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Timestamp": {
                            "$date": {
                              "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                            }
                          },
                          "UUTHistory": [
                            {
                              "ClockingCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Offset": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Status": "",
                              "StartCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Timestamp": {
                                "$date": {
                                  "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "UUTId": "TS221",
                          "ClockingCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Status": "Steht",
                          "StartCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Offset": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Timestamp": {
                            "$date": {
                              "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                            }
                          },
                          "UUTHistory": [
                            {
                              "ClockingCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Offset": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Status": "",
                              "StartCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Timestamp": {
                                "$date": {
                                  "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      "ChannelCycles": {
                        "$numberInt": "0"
                      },
                      "NodeName": ""
                    },
                    {
                      "ChannelCycles": {
                        "$numberInt": "0"
                      },
                      "UUTs": [
                        {
                          "UUTId": "TS230",
                          "ClockingCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Status": "Steht",
                          "StartCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Offset": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Timestamp": {
                            "$date": {
                              "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                            }
                          },
                          "UUTHistory": [
                            {
                              "ClockingCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Offset": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Status": "",
                              "StartCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Timestamp": {
                                "$date": {
                                  "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      "NodeName": ""
                    },
                    {
                      "UUTs": [
                        {
                          "UUTId": "TS240",
                          "ClockingCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Status": "Steht",
                          "StartCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Offset": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Timestamp": {
                            "$date": {
                              "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                            }
                          },
                          "UUTHistory": [
                            {
                              "ClockingCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Offset": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Status": "",
                              "StartCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Timestamp": {
                                "$date": {
                                  "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      "ChannelCycles": {
                        "$numberInt": "0"
                      },
                      "NodeName": ""
                    },
                    {
                      "ChannelCycles": {
                        "$numberInt": "0"
                      },
                      "UUTs": [
                        {
                          "UUTId": "TS250",
                          "ClockingCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Status": "Steht",
                          "StartCycles": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Offset": {
                            "$numberInt": "0"
                          },
                          "Timestamp": {
                            "$date": {
                              "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                            }
                          },
                          "UUTHistory": [
                            {
                              "ClockingCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Offset": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Status": "",
                              "StartCycles": {
                                "$numberInt": "0"
                              },
                              "Timestamp": {
                                "$date": {
                                  "$numberLong": "946681200000"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      "NodeName": ""
                    }
                  ],
                  "ConnectionType": "Opcua",
                  "Title": "Taktverteiler_1",
                  "Link": "http://192.168.0.6:8080/tv_webvisu.htm",
                  "PropertyNames": [
                    "P-Line",
                    "Modus",
                    "Status",
                    "Freq [Hz]",
                    "Verwendung"
                  ],
                  "Nodes": [
                    "|var|CPX-CEC-S1-V3.Application.PersistentVars.ar_str_p1_p2",
                    "|var|CPX-CEC-S1-V3.Application.OPC_UA_Variablen_Dashboard.ar_str_Normal_VE_OPC_UA",
                    "|var|CPX-CEC-S1-V3.Application.OPC_UA_Variablen_Dashboard.ar_str_Status_OPC_UA",
                    "|var|CPX-CEC-S1-V3.Application.PersistentVars.ar_r_Frequenz_Kanal_X",
                    "|var|CPX-CEC-S1-V3.Application.OPC_UA_Variablen_Dashboard.ar_str_Verwendung"
                  ],
                  "StartStopNodes": [
                    "|var|CPX-CEC-C1-V3.Application.GVL.b_Button_Stimulation_Starten_aktive_Kanaele",
                    "|var|CPX-CEC-C1-V3.Application.GVL.b_alle_Stopp"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class ServerTreeVm
    {
        [BsonElement("Countries")]
        public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        public string ActiveEnduranceTest { get; set; }

        public string ActiveDistributor { get; set; }

    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Country
    {
        [BsonElement("Cities")]
        public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("CountryName")]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class City
    {
        [BsonElement("EnduranceTests")]
        public List<Endurance> EnduranceTests { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("CityName")]
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Endurance
    {
        [BsonElement("ClockDistributor")]
        public List<EnduranceInformation> EnduranceInfo { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("EnduranceTestName")]
        public string EnduranceTestName { get; set; }
    }


    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class UUT
    {
        [BsonElement("UUTId")]
        public string UutId { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ClockingCycles")]
        public double ClockingCycles { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("StartCycles")]
        public double StartCycles { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Offset")]
        public double Offset { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("UUTHistory")]
        public List<UUTHistory> UUTHistory { get; set; }
    }


    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class UUTHistory
    {
        [BsonElement("ClockingCycles")]
        public double ClockingCycles { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("StartCycles")]
        public double StartCycles { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Offset")]
        public double Offset { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }


    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class ChannelObjects
    {
        [BsonElement("UUTs")]
        public List<UUT> Uuts { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ChannelCycles")]
        public double ChannelCycles { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("NodeName")]
        public string NodeName { get; set; }

    }


    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class EnduranceInformation
    {
        [BsonElement("IP")]
        public string Ip { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("PropertyNames")]
        public List<string> PropertyNames { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Nodes")]
        public List<string> Nodes { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Channels")]
        public List<ChannelObjects> Channels { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ConnectionType")]
        public String ConnectionType { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("StartStopNodes")]
        public List<string> StartStopNodeNames { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The MongoDB C# driver returns data as BsonDocument() type.  You have custom models.  You have not specified what framework you use to serialize/deserialize between the MongoDB Driver and your custom models.  What do you use for your DAL?

Comment: By the way, wholesale updating the document (that is to say replace the entire document to update a single field) is expensive and performs poorly.

Comment: I use the official C# Mongodb driver available from Nuget packages. Link: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your real problem, which is how to use the C# mongo driver, but this might help.  I am placing it here instead of comments above because I want to illustrate some code concepts and need the formatting options...

Please allow me to elaborate on some points...

Your code has the following lambda query criteria...

```
(a => a.EnduranceInfo.Any(b=>b.Title== "Taktverteiler_1"))
```

... but your example documents do not have this field.  This will cause no documents to be found to update.  Similarly, since `EnduranceInfo` does not exist the following lambda query expression ....

```
(a => a.EnduranceInfo.Any(b => b.Channels.Any(c=>c.Uuts.Any(d=>d.UutId == "TS220"))))
```

... will also fail to find matching documents.

I often compare MongoDB to RDBMS systems.  When constructing a standard 'find()' operation in Mongo the first criteria a query.  This is horrible name because it isn't a query, instead it is the 'find a matching document' clause.  If you create a MongoDB find() command and providing only the first parameter (assuming a match is found) you will receive the entire document.  This means the first parameter is equivalent to the 'WHERE' clause in a traditional RDBMS system.  No 'SELECT' clause has yet been established.

So, your question is more targeted.  Not only do you want to find a specific document to update, you also want to update a specific part of the found document.  The find portion of the query finds the document.  Other portions of the query then must be defined to identify what part of the document to update.  Your code attempts to target a specific portion of the document via the two lines of code...

```
var enduranceUpdate = update.Set("Countries.$.Cities.$.EnduranceTest.$.ClockDistributor.$.Channels.$.UUTs.$", uutObj);
collectionEndurance.UpdateOne(enduranceTestFound, enduranceUpdate);
```

I think you have the right idea, but syntactically the find argument `enduranceTestFound` will not have any found documents per earlier discussion.  The option `enduranceUpdate` is malformed.  The use of '$' indicates you want to update the first occurrance of an array element.   See MongoDB documentation on '$' at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/.  You will see they specifically state...

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element
>   that matches the query document, and the array field must appear as
>   part of the query document.

In order to understand what my code needs to do I generally resolve to identifying the query first using the most rudimentary tools available.  For RDBMS systems that is usually a SQL window.  For MongoDB that is mongo shell.  My theory is that if I can create a query that executes properly in mongo shell, then I simply need to transpose it to the framework of my code, in your case C# driver specific syntax.  By using the arrayFilters option of an update command I can create a very targeted query.  This query finds the proper document via the 'find' portion, then identifies the $set command to target specific fields to update, then using the arrayFilters option I can use a placeholder variable to define what specific part of the document I wish to update.  Here is my example:

```
db.enduranceTest.update(
    { "Countries.Cities.EnduranceTests.EnduranceTestName": "endurance1" }, 
    { $set: {
        "Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTests.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[myplaceholder].ClockingCycles" : 2000,
        "Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTests.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[myplaceholder].Status" : "Running",
        "Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTests.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[myplaceholder].StartCycles" : 0,
        "Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTests.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[myplaceholder].Offset" : 2000,
        "Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTests.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[myplaceholder].Timestamp" : new Date(),
        "Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTests.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[myplaceholder].UUTHistory" : null,
      } 
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        { "myplaceholder.UUTId" : "TS220" }
      ]
    }
)
```

Lots of good stuff here.  Notice the `myplaceholder` variable name and how it is referenced in both the arrayFilter area as well as the $set operator?  Notice the `$[]` to indicate any array.  You have so many nested arrays I needed to add 5 `$[]` operators in the $set for each field.  Notice I am setting field by field.  I could have replaced the entire `$[myplaceholder]` - I believe this was your original approach.  Notice my 'find' command is limited to "Countries.Cities.EnduranceTests.EnduranceTestName", the EnduranceInfo doesn't exist so I don't include it.

Anyways, I look forward to your response.  This was a fun exercise to work through, and as a result I have a much stronger understanding of arrayFilters.  I suspect the C# driver has a construct for arrayFilters and understanding how to apply them remains a task.  Hopefully looking at the raw MQL you can find options to transpose into C# specific code.

Answer (score 0):

- If you look closely in the JSON structure `(a => a.EnduranceInfo.Any(b=>b.Title== "Taktverteiler_1"))` "title":"Taktverteiler_1" does exist down in the structure.
- Regarding your solution i find it good. but my mongodb server installed does not support Array filters. Hence i can't tell that the solution will work. When i use your solution without array filters than i get

  `var enduranceUpdate = update.Set(               "Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTest.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[0].ClockingCycles", uutObj.ClockingCycles);`

  Mongodb exception cannot use the part (Countries of Countries.$[].Cities.$[].EnduranceTest.$[].ClockDistributor.$[].Channels.$[].UUTs.$[0].ClockingCycles) to traverse the element.
- I could get one of my solution to work but it is not the best solution since i need to know the index of each array before updating it dynamically.

  ```
  ` UUT uutObj = new UUT
                  {
                    Status = "laüft",
                    UutId = "TS220",
                    ClockingCycles = 2000,
                    Offset = 100,
                    StartCycles = 0,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                    UUTHistory = null
                  };

      var enduranceUpdate = update.Set("Countries.0.Cities.0.EnduranceTest.0.ClockDistributor.0.Channels.0.UUTs.$", uutObj);`
  ```

  `var enduranceTestFound = filterVM.And(
                  Builders<ServerTreeVm>.Filter.Where(x => x.Countries.Any(y =>
                      y.Cities.Any(z => z.EnduranceTests.Any(a => a.EnduranceInfo.Any(b => b.Channels.Any(c=>c.Uuts.Any(d=>d.UutId == "TS220"))))))));
      UpdateResult res = collectionEndurance.UpdateOne(enduranceTestFound, enduranceUpdate);`